# Маленькая задачка по jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сей код должен был существенно облегчить сайт http запросами, так как по желанию клиента в каждом товаре должно крутится до 10 фоток. Решил сделать это фоном, все норм работает только есть один маленький нюанс. В переменной widthImgBox скапливается значение и при клике на другую фотку - оно применяется и там. Вопрос - как сделать чтобы при вызове функции на другом блоке переменная или обнулялась или еще может есть какие-то варианты как это сделать фоном (я новичок если что).

```
var widthImgBox = 0;
$('.next').on('click', function(){
    var hiddenImg = $(this).siblings().find('.tov-item-img');
    widthImgBox = widthImgBox - 290;
    hiddenImg.css({
    'background-position-x': widthImgBox
    });
    return false;
});
$('.prev').click( function(){
    var hiddenImg = $(this).siblings().find('.tov-item-img');
    widthImgBox = widthImgBox + 290;
    hiddenImg.css({
    'background-position-x': widthImgBox
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", readyHTML);
function readyHTML() {
        var arrovnext = document.querySelectorAll('.tov-item .next');
        if (arrovnext) {
        for (var i = arrovnext.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arrovnext[i].addEventListener("click", function (event){ event.preventDefault(); return false});
            arrovnext[i].addEventListener("click", next_bg_img);
        }
        }
        var arrovprev = document.querySelectorAll('.tov-item .prev');
        if (arrovprev) {
        for (var i = arrovprev.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arrovprev[i].addEventListener("click", function (event){ event.preventDefault(); return false});
            arrovprev[i].addEventListener("click", prev_bg_img);
        }   
        }
    }
    function next_bg_img(event) {
        var bgPoz = this.parentNode.querySelector('.tov-item-img').style.backgroundPositionX;
        var nextImg = Number(bgPoz.replace('px','')) - 290;
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.tov-item-img').style.backgroundPositionX = nextImg + 'px';
    }
    function prev_bg_img() {
        var bgPoz = this.parentNode.querySelector('.tov-item-img').style.backgroundPositionX;
        var prevImg = Number(bgPoz.replace('px','')) + 290;
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.tov-item-img').style.backgroundPositionX = prevImg + 'px';  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var next = 0;
var ImgBgPosition = 0;
var flag = false;
$('.next').on('click', function(){
  if (flag) return false;
  flag = true;
  next = parseInt($(this).parent('.animated').find('.tov-item-img').css('background-position-x'),10);//Берем только число
  ImgBgPosition = next - 290;
  $(this).parent('.animated').find('.tov-item-img').animate({backgroundPositionX:ImgBgPosition}, function(){flag = false;});
  return false;
});
$('.prev').on('click', function(){
   if (flag) return false;
   flag = true;
   next = parseInt($(this).parent('.animated').find('.tov-item-img').css('background-position-x'),10);//Берем только число
   ImgBgPosition = next + 290;
   $(this).parent('.animated').find('.tov-item-img').animate({backgroundPositionX:ImgBgPosition}, function(){flag = false;});
   return false;
});
```

Вообщем вот код этот можете сразу вставить к себе на сайт.
Стили для класса `.animated` уберите и у класса `.tov-item-img` уберите `transition: .5s;`

`function(){flag = false;}` предотвратит быстрые клики. Как только анимация закончится, будет выполнена следующая.

обращение к элементам сделал более грамотное.

Вот собственно сам [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/64ndb0hx/4/)

Стрелки в примере оказались внизу под товаром, не стал исправлять, т.к. это не критично:)

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял то оно будет листать всего один раз, то есть один раз - 290 или + 290, переменная таким образом не перезаписывается и дальше не листает(

Comment: Вот сайт если что http://lipkit.com.ua/test/  дело в том что количевство картинок может колебаться от 2 до 10. Не понял вопроса о последовательности чисел, есть шаг в 290px который в зависимости от next и prev добавляет или отнимает 290px, как последовательность чисел поможет в решении вопроса?

Comment: У меня что-то крутится в голове типо добавить всем background-position и чтобы значение переменной формировалось отталкиваясь от его текущего background-position, то есть при клике как-то с помощью this брать значение данного блока и к нему уже  плюсовать или минусовать, но я не могу собрать все эти мысли  в кучу и написать код

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
var ImgBgPosition;
var ThisBg;
$('.next').on('click', function(){
   ImgBgPosition = $(this).siblings().find('.tov-item-img').css("background-position-x");
   ThisBg = $(this).siblings().find('.tov-item-img');
   ImgBgPosition = ImgBgPosition.replace('px','');
   ImgBgPosition = ImgBgPosition - 290;
   ThisBg.css({
      'background-position-x': ImgBgPosition
   });
   return false;
});
$('.prev').on('click', function(){
   ImgBgPosition = $(this).siblings().find('.tov-item-img').css("background-position-x");
   ThisBg = $(this).siblings().find('.tov-item-img');
   ImgBgPosition = ImgBgPosition.replace('px','');
   ImgBgPosition = Number(ImgBgPosition) + 290;
   ThisBg.css({
      'background-position-x': ImgBgPosition
   });
   return false;
});
```

Но появилась еще одна проблема, когда быстро нажимаешь (раньше чем отработает transition) то шаг сбивается, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Верстка у Вас на сайте действительна, который Вы мне показали? Если да, то сделаю пример по ней.

Comment: да, верстка та же

Comment: Проверяйте, сделал.

Comment: Смотрю у Вас на сайте быстро прокручиваются картинки и все хорошо, как добились?

Comment: Попробовал сделать на чистом js по тому же самому принципу, на мое удивление все отлично стало работать. Он как-то не берет промежуточное значение во время трансформации фона, а берет то значение которое получается в конечном результате, не зависимо от того сколько раз и с какой скоростью кликаешь, так и остановился на этом варианте, он идеально подходит как как по мне.

Comment: А можете пример выложить, пожалуйста. Пригодится:)